# ASYNC in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I'm kind of new to async in Node.JS and callbacks. Could you please let me know if this is the right way to have an async call?

```
function myFunc(schema) {
    async.each(Object.keys(schema), function(variable) {
        for (item in schema[variable]) {
            for (field in schema[variable][item]) {
                // Some operations go here                   
            }
            createDB(item, schema[variable][item]);
        }
    }); 
}


function CreateDB(name, new_items) {
    ddb.createTable(selected_field.name, {hash: ['id', ddb.schemaTypes().number],
        range: ['time', ddb.schemaTypes().string],
        AttributeDefinitions: new_items
    },
    {read: 1, write: 1}, function(err, details) {
        console.log("The DB is now created!");
    });
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Nope. your async.each iterator isn't executing the "done" argument and doesn't have a callback (making it relatively pointless)

Comment: What end result were you going for? only one createDB executing at a time? being able to know when their all created?

Comment: since it is table_create, I can have them simultaneously, it does not hurt and it is better in terms of performance

Comment: Do you need to know when it's done creating the databases?

Comment: Yes!... I prefer to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be one way to do it, all tough I'm no fan of callbacks, I prefer to use [promises](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird).
This approach will just propagate all errors to the `cb1`, if you want to handle errors anywhere in between you should [wrap them or try to fix stuff](http://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors).

If you're gonna do async operations in that inner for loop you are in for some additional async refactor fun.

```
function myFunc(schema, cb1) {
    async.each(Object.keys(schema), function(variable, cb2) {
        async.each(Object.keys(schema[variable]), function(item, cb3) {
            for (var field in schema[variable][item]) {
                // Some operations go here
            }
            createDB(item, schema[variable][item], cb3);
        }, cb2);
    }, cb1);
}

function CreateDB(name, new_items, cb) {
    ddb.createTable(selected_field.name, {hash: ['id', ddb.schemaTypes().number],
            range: ['time', ddb.schemaTypes().string],
            AttributeDefinitions: new_items
        },
        {read: 1, write: 1}, cb);
}
```